# Join table on SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I make this work ? I have a table `u_uzivatele` and I want to join it on table `b_objednavky` but also I don't want rows from table `u_uzivatele` to be joined that can be joined to table `bw_paid_orders` and doesn't meet `WHERE` clause. Right now, the `SELECT` statement returns table with rows from table `uzivatele` that are also in table `bw_paid_orders` and meet criteria on WHERE clause. But I cannot join it on table `u_uzivatele` because there are multiple rows returned.

```
SELECT STMT

FROM b_objednavky INNER JOIN u_uzivatele ON b_objednavky.uzivatel = 
( 
       SELECT u_uzivatele.id 
       FROM   u_uzivatele 
       JOIN   bw_paid_orders 
       ON     u_uzivatele.id = bw_paid_orders.user_id 
       WHERE  bw_paid_orders.active_thru < now() + interval '6 months' ) uzivatele
```

Comment: `select ... from table join ( subquery ) on ...`

Comment: where should I use the select that you suggest ?.. Basically I want to join table on subquery

Comment: See a_horse_with_no_name's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You want to only join `u_uzivatele` records for which **not exists** a certain entry in `bw_paid_orders`. So use `NOT EXISTS` or the simpler `NOT IN`.

```
select ...
from b_objednavky o
join u_uzivatele u on  u.id = o.uzivatel
                   and u.id not in (select user_id from bw_paid_orders po 
                                    where active_thru < now() + interval '6 months')
```

Comment: This actually looks like it is what I need. But overall it still doesn't work, I need to check if this returns something else then I want